# Cast Map<String,String> to Map<Long,Long>

Tags: java

I have the following code in a class which extends `LazyDataModel` of Primefaces

```
@Override
    public List<Project> load(int first, int pageSize,
            String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
```

In the above filters is of type `Map<String, String>`

In my Hibernate Entity class I have the following

```
private Long projectNo; // with getters and setters
```

and in DAO class I have the following as well to do a search in JSF page and return results

```
public void getProjects(ProjectQueryData data) { 

Map<String, String> filters = data.getFilters();
// ....
....

String projectNo = filters.get("projectNo");
List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            if (projectNo!= null) {
                ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class,
                        "projectNo");               
                Predicate predicate = cb.equal(emp.get(Project_.projectNo),
                        pexp);
                criteria.add(predicate);
            }
TypedQuery<Project> q = entityManager.createQuery(c);
TypedQuery<Long> countquery = entityManager.createQuery(countQ);
q.setParameter("projectNo", projectNo); // error in this line
countquery.setParameter("projectNo", projectNo);
```

When I execute the above I am getting the following exception

```
Hibernate Parameter value [89457] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]
```

because `projectNo` is of Long.

My question is how can I cast `Map<String,String>` to `Map<Long,Long>` so that I will not get an error in this line `q.setParameter("projectNo", projectNo);`

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: modify in the entity class as string while setting the value.

Comment: Does the map contain strings that are valid numbers? If so, why not just convert `String projectNo` to a `Long`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast `Map<String,String> to Map<Long,Long>` , Why don't you use `Map<Object,Object>` or `Map<String,Object>`if your parameter Map is expecting all data types.

In this case it seems like you can also achieve the fix by casting it to the string or long before setting in Map,

```
String.valueOf(projectNo);

or 

Long.toString(projectNo);
```

wherever required.

Comment: I would rather use Map<String,Object> and Long.valueOf(projectNo) but I guess this is also what you meant, right?

Comment: Map<String,Object> is good idea to store parameters map which accept variable data type but for some reason OP is trying to cast Long,Long to String,String